# Swift Image View not filling borders correctly

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Here is my image:

[image: imageView]

And this is my code:

```
cell.itemImage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.itemImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
cell.itemImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.itemImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.itemImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

cell.itemImage.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8831475377, green: 0, blue: 0.1722375751, alpha: 1)
```

I just want to fill the photo to the assigned height and width of the image and just have a simple corner radius. But apparently for me it's not working.

Comment: Hi @matt basically fill the square box to the white borders with the image.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? How does the image view get its size?

Comment: @matt I set the image view with a height and width constraint